# Reliable code for communication between two python processes

Tags: python, subprocess, ipc, pipe

I need reliable Python code for communication between two python processes. I wrote such codes that uses pipes. But I have some doubt. What are the disadvantages? Are there other ways?

Main module:

```
import subprocess, pickle
data=["A","B","C"]
s = pickle.dumps(data)
se=s.encode("string_escape") # produce a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code
p=subprocess.Popen(["python", "server.py"],stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(input=se)
s2=stdout.decode("string_escape")
data = pickle.loads(s2)
print data
```

server.py:

```
import pickle,sys
s=sys.stdin.read().decode("string_escape")
data = pickle.loads(s)
s=pickle.dumps(data)
se=s.encode("string_escape")
sys.stdout.write(se)
```

Comment: My opinion that server.py cannot use `print` command.

Comment: The disadvantage is that we can not write to the standard output anything else in server.py. Only what we need to pass. I'm trying to find a convenient way of communication between Abaqus/CAE python script and other python process.

Comment: [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html?highlight=mmap#mmap) might work better.